# MD5Decrypter.co.uk reverses md5 hashes?

Tags: md5, salt

There is a site called http://www.MD5Decrypter.co.uk where when you give a md5 hash, it gives the original string. How is that possible. As far as I know md5 is an irreversible hash algorithm or is it? 
Secondly, can salt be used along with md5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

md5 is a hash algorithme so it allows two words to have the same hashcode. I you do not trust me, I can hash a 5-letter word, 10-letter word, 128-letter word with md5 and it will give me 32 characters every time.

The probleme is that md5 is not cryptographicaly secured. One can analyse it and guess what could have been hash. But the technique used by the site you posted is the rainbow table.
It can also be a dictionary, but it is less common with md5.

If you use a salt with your md5, this generator will not find anything until the rainbow table with your salt is filled.

md5 is usefull to sign a file, a cookie, or the name of a cryptography algorithm. It is not secured to store passwords. Some languages advice you to use whirlpool, bloswfish, salsa20 or sha512 instead of md2/5 sha 1/2/256

Comment: So reversing it is not possible? Because what you are saying is that they are using rainbow tables(which contains precalculated hashes)